# Converting Arraylists with abstract objects

Tags: java, object, inheritance, arraylist

Good morning all,

While writing my GUI I ran into a problem with my Arraylist.
In my Vereniging class there is a ArrayList containing Persoon objects, which are either Lid or Medewerker.
Now what I need is to filter all the Lid objects from that list and make a new Arraylist with Lid objects.
Does anyone know if this is possible?
I've tried running a enhanced for loop and adding the objects to a new Arraylist but it says the datatype doesnt meet (trying to add Persoon to a Lid list)

Classes;

Vereniging

```
public class Vereniging {

private String naam;

private ArrayList<Persoon> personen;
private ArrayList<Vliegtuig> vliegtuigen;
private ArrayList<Vlucht> vluchten;
private ArrayList<Hangaar> hangaars;

private DataHandler handler = new Database();

public Vereniging(String naam){
    this.naam = naam;

    personen = new ArrayList<>();
    vliegtuigen = new ArrayList<>();
    vluchten = new ArrayList<>();
    hangaars = new ArrayList<>();
}

public ArrayList<Persoon> getPersonen() {
    return personen;
}
```

Persoon

```
public abstract class Persoon implements Comparable<Persoon>{

private String voornaam;
private String tussenvoegsel;
private String achternaam;
private String woonplaats;
private String geslacht;
private String rekeningnr;

Persoon(String voornaam, String tussenvoegsel, String achternaam, String 
woonplaats,
               String geslacht, String rekeningnr){
    this.voornaam = voornaam;
    this.tussenvoegsel = tussenvoegsel;
    this.achternaam = achternaam;
    this.woonplaats = woonplaats;
    this.geslacht = geslacht;
    this.rekeningnr = rekeningnr;
}
```

Lid

```
public class Lid extends Persoon {

private String gebnaam;
private String wachtwoord;
private String rol;

public Lid(String voornaam, String tussenvoegsel, String achternaam, String woonplaats, String geslacht,
           String rekeningnr, String gebnaam, String wachtwoord, String rol) {
    super(voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam, woonplaats, geslacht, rekeningnr);
    this.gebnaam = gebnaam;
    this.wachtwoord = wachtwoord;
    this.rol = rol;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the type comparison operator: [`instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2). Which lets you compare if a variable is an instance of a class (or a subclass).

See the following example which iterates over the `personen` list and then uses the `instanceof` to determine if it in fact is an instance of `Lid` or not:

```
List<Lid> lids = new ArrayList<>();
for(Persoon persoon : personen){
    if(persoon instanceof Lid){
        // safe cast and add to lids
        lids.add((Lid) persoon);
    }
}
```

If you happen to use Java 8, you can make us of the new Stream API:

```
List<Lid> lids = personen.stream() // create a stream of persoonen
    .filter(Lid.class::isInstance) // equivalent to using instanceof
    .map(Lid.class::cast)          // equivalent to casting
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // creating a list
```

Comment: Oh my, you saved me from a big problem, thanks a lot for your quick and clear answer! I'll accept the answer when the timer lets me!

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you want to add object of parent into array list of child type.
So when your are iterating through list of persoon, check type of persoon by using **instanceOf** then type case that to Lid and add it to your new list.

Hope this will resolve your problem.

**More Enhance solution can be as following.**

```
personen.stream().filter(p->p instanceOf Lid).map(p->(Lid)p).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

by using stream API of Java 8 you can do it in a single line.
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your time!